# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Tags: python, json, csv

I am using python 3.9

I get this error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

when I trying to do:

```
import json

print(json.loads("['product', 'font', 'graphics', 'photo caption', 'brand', 'advertising', 'technology', 'text', 'graphic design', 'competition']"))
```

But it works fine when I did:

```
print(json.loads('["a", "b", "c"]'))
```

It seems the error is associated with the quotation mark. But may I ask why is that? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that this is just how the JSON spec works. All strings must be double quoted as you can see from the diagram in the middle of [Introducing JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

However, you can parse that string in python using `ast.literal_eval()` rather than `json.loads()`.

```py
import ast
print(ast.literal_eval("['product', 'font', 'graphics', 'photo caption', 'brand', 'advertising', 'technology', 'text', 'graphic design', 'competition']"))
```